# Can't upload GitHub artifacts "EACCES: permission denied, stat"

Tags: github-actions

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to upload the artifacts of my C app on I built on Windows using msys2,  when trying to access the **`soft.exe`** file. The error message I'm receiving is:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, stat 'D:\a\softbochs\softbochs\build\soft.exe'
```

Here is my upload artifact part of my GitHub actions YML  :

```
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4.3.1
        with:
          name: softbochs
          path: D:\a\softbochs\softbochs\build\
```

I've checked the file path, and the file does exist in the specified location. However, it seems like there's a permission issue preventing access to the file.

What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting extensively, I've devised a very hacky solution to this issue. By compressing the project using `tar -czvf softbochs.tar.gz ./build`, I successfully compressed the project which in turn adjusted the permissions automatically. Subsequently, I uploaded the resulting artifacts via the path: `D:\a\softbochs\softbochs\softbochs.tar.gz`.